# MSSQL Transaction never returns error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, rollback

I have a mssql code which never returns error. Here are the codes:

```
alter proc USP_Havale
@GonderenID int,
@AliciID int,
@GonderilenPara money
as
begin try
    begin transaction
        update Hesap set 
        Para = Para - @GonderilenPara
        where HesapID = @GonderenID

        update Hesap set
        Para = Para + @GonderilenPara
        where HesapID = @AliciID
    commit tran
end try
begin catch
    rollback tran
    print 'error'
end catch
```

And I run the code like as following:

```
exec USP_Havale @GonderenID=1,@AliciID=5,@GonderilenPara=1500
```

The problem is that id 5 does not exists. Hence code should return false and print 'error'. Instead, it returns the following:

```
 1 row(s) affected.
 0 row(s) affected.
```

What is wrong in here?

Comment: Your update statements don't consider it to be an error just becuase they haven't found anything to update. I assume you are looking for an error message if nothing was updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every `UPDATE` statement you could add the next check:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RAISERROR('@GonderenID and/or @AliciID doesn't exist.', 16, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have a simple update statement in your sp and you haven't raised an error if the passed id does not exist, therefore it simple tried to update a row where id = 5 and no row is updates its not an error, its just the command did not update any row.

If you want your stored procedure to raise an error if passed id does not exists then you need to explicitly raise an error inside your catch block, which will make your control to jump to catch block, something like this...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_Havale
    @GonderenID int,
    @AliciID int,
    @GonderilenPara money
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
      -- do a check here before executing update statements
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM Hesap 
                    WHERE HesapID = @AliciID)
         BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Error id does not exist',16,1)
         END

    -- if test passes now open transaction and do your stuff
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            update Hesap 
             set  Para = Para - @GonderilenPara
            where HesapID = @GonderenID

            update Hesap 
            set Para = Para + @GonderilenPara
            where HesapID = @AliciID
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
         -- Now since the error can happen even before
         -- you open a transaction add this check
         IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
           BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
           END
            PRINT 'error'
    END CATCH
END
```